240v 50amp receptacle to subpanel for 120v devices
I have a system that consists of three 120v 1200w heaters and a 120v 250w motor..  Can I run a line from my welder outlet (240v 50amp) to a small breaker box to create multiple 15 amp circuits?

I think code will allow you to remove the outlet and hook up the panel to the wires/cable, if the cable includes a neutral wire.  Then run the circuits, including the welder from the panel.  After you would need to choose the welder or the heaters being on.

Does the socket have 4 wires?  Is there a compelling  reason you need to use 120V heaters? Note that 240V baseboards are cheap, and 120V space heaters sold in stores are not safe or legal for unattended use.

If that welder outlet has a neutral, yes you can.
This breaker box would be a subpanel and the neutral and ground should be remain separated from each other.
You will want to split the load across each phase but it's not strictly required given that the max load you are planning is 120 V 32 amps, well under the 40 Amps continuous draw you can put on each phase of the 240V 50 amps outlet.

Quite a few cables used to connect welder receptacles are /3 plus ground.  So good chance OP has an unused neutral handy.
